# Android Navigation Back after successful registration activity

Tags: android

I have an `Activity A`. `Activity A` has a button called `Add to Favorites`.

If the user is not logged in then it will take him to `Activity B` (the login page). The login page has a button `If New User please Register`

If user is not registered then onclicking `If New User please Register` it will take him to `Activity C` (Sign Up form).

After successfully filling the form it will go to `Activity D` for entering OTP.

Now if the OTP is correct I want to go back to `Activity A` from `Activity D`

So how to do this with startAcitivity.

Comment: Look for `startActivityForResult` and `onActivityResult`.

Comment: You would need a chain of start activity for result. Would start login activity for result, then sign up activity for result then start OTP activity for result. It would be easier to pass a custom intent flag through these activities and handle it in activity D to route back to correct activity with clear top. There is not really a result you are returning either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start activity A with ClearTop.

```
Intent activityA = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class);
activityA.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(a);
```

This flag starts the activity in question and clears all other activities that are on top of it in the stack. It will launch activity A from its previous state. So if there was an activity beneath it in the stack then the back button will still work correctly.

Here is some useful information on the backstack and how to manage it.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

Comment: also if login is activated from menu. Then should i mention clear top for every activity with menu containing login

Comment: Make it a flow you can use. If user can enter your app and use it without logging in and you want them to be able to force login for feature and return to wherever they were at. Then they should go through that flow. Probably clicking on login from menu is not one of those actions because user actively clicked on login and expects to be presented a login screen. But if by default you are returning to menu after they login then it would be the same flow.

Comment: my idea is to to allow users who already used the app can login and no need to wait till the feature. thank you